# Android Wear Communicate With Phone Hardware

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Hi I have this simple code on Android Wear I need a bit of help everything works well if I'm using the phone alone the problem I have is that I taught Android wear will use automatically the Phone hardware for sound and all that good stuff.
Here is my test code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)     findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

        imageButtonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonOne);
        textviewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewOne);
        imageButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textviewOne.setText("Hello World!");
                soundOne() ;
            }
        });
    }
    public void soundOne() {
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone one = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            one.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_file_1);
        // media.start() ;
        // Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep() ;
    }
});
```

It call the sound but because watches doesn't have speakers won't sound. I want the phone to make the sound. Please if someone can help me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Android Wear devices **will** play sound if a bluetooth headset is attached, if you need sound to play on the phone you need to use the [Wearable Data Layer](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) and probably more specifically the [Message API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to send a message to your phone app. Your phone app would implement a [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) which would be triggered by the incoming message and would play the sound on the phone.

Note: it is **much** more common for Wear apps to vibrate (via the [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) to draw attention rather than play sounds on the phone. Many Wear users use the 'Mute connected phone' option to effectively silence their phone so a sound coming from it may be quite unexpected.

Comment: Im a bit lost I want to do something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nickapps.wear.findmyphone&hl=en                                                     I will use more phone hardware  but I'm stuck sending the bluetooth command to call the phone.

Comment: You send commands from the Wear device to the phone via the Wearable Data Layer, as I said. Then your phone app directly interacts with the phone hardware.